# Scala: type mismatch when invoking fun with Int

Tags: arrays, scala

In my limited experience with Scala, there is a error in my code:

```
class TagCalculation {
    def test_string(arg1: String,arg2: String) = arg1 + " " + arg2
    def test_int(arg1: Int,arg2: Int) = arg1 + arg2
  }
val get_test = new TagCalculation
//test int, by the way it's Ok for String
val test_int_para = Array(1,2)
val argtypes2 = test_int_para.map(_.getClass)
val method2 = get_test.getClass.getMethod("test_int", argtypes2: _*)
method2.invoke(get_test,test_int_para: _*)
```

Outputs:

> console>:29: error: type mismatch;
>   found   : Array[Int] 
>  required:
>   Array[_ <: Object] 
>                   method2.invoke(get_test,test_int_para: _*)

Why did this error happened?

Comment: Probably this will help you clarify: https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/128.html
On a side note: your post doesn't look like a question.

Comment: Arrays in Scala are *invariant* but in Java they are *covariant*. You'll need to cast it to `Array[Object]` (or declare it as that type)...

Comment: @DeusEx - I'm newer for using stackoverflow(It's very very good), so I may make some mistakes for its style. Oh, is there something to make my question well for a "question"? Thanks in advance：）

Comment: @insan-e - could you  provided more details about your use case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`invoke()`'s second parameter has type `Array[_ <: Object]`. That means, that type of passed array should extend `Object`. In Scala `Object` is synonym to `AnyRef`, and `Int` isn't `AnyRef` subtype, but is `AnyVal` subtype actually. Here is more detailed explanation: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html

You passed `Array[Int]` as second parameter, that's why error happened. You need to pass `Array[_ <: Object]` instead.

So, what you really need is to pass `Integer` wrappers, which are `AnyRef`s, explicitly. You can transform all array `Int`s to `Integer`s using `Integer.valueOf` method. Then, `invoke()` method just works:

```
scala> method2.invoke(get_test, test_int_para.map(Integer.valueOf): _*)
res2: Object = 3
```

Comment: great solution Evgeny

Comment: thanks, resolved. there is a more complex for me: val test_int_para = Array(1,"string",df),  you can see :Int, String, Dataframe, how about that

Comment: @meng you need to pass Array(Integer.valueOf(1), "string", df) into invoke method. Basically, you need to replace all primitives (such as Ints) with their wrappers (such as Integers).

Comment: @Evgeny Veretennikov -  I also miss a List[Any]. Could you give me some detail even pseudocode for "def test_mix(arg1:Int,arg2:String,arg3:List[Any],df: DataFrame)"?

Comment: @meng you should pass `classOf[List[Any]])` as third element of `argTypes`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Integer.valueOf` (or `Double`, or `Long`, etc. etc.) there is a much simpler solution:

```
val test_int_para = Array[AnyRef](1,2)
```

Or if you already have `val params: Array[Any]`, e.g. `val params = Array(1,"string",df)`:

```
val paramsAsObjects = params.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
someMethod.invoke(someObject, paramsAsObjects: _*)
```